# Implementing cdc and deduplication on AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, duplicates, etl, cdc, data-lake

I want to build a Data Lake in AWS S3 and asking my self how to work with CDC. I wanna avoid loading the whole data from the sources and furthermore I wanna avoid duplicates in the target. Are there some proven methodologies how to tackle that?

Comment: Can you deambiguate the usage of CDC achronism?  Does it means IBM CDC (IDR)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following blog:

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/loading-ongoing-data-lake-changes-with-aws-dms-and-aws-glue/

The deduplication is done by AWS Glue by running jobs on raw data. This dumps data to another bucket which will be mirror replication of your source database.